# print on console and text file simultaneously python

Tags: python, file, text, recursion, console

I am trying to output comments on python console and at the same time, saving into a text file and it should run recursively. I found a code  and modified:

```
import sys

def write(input_text):
    print("Coming through stdout")
    # stdout is saved
    save_stdout = sys.stdout

    fh = open(path,"w")
    sys.stdout = fh
    print(input_text)

    # return to normal:
    sys.stdout = save_stdout
    fh.close()
 def testing():
    write('go')
```

I reuse this command, and it only saved the last received print data. any clue?
Thanks

Comment: I you're open for an alternative: I found this on the python mailing list, which looks nice for me: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-May/438106.html

Comment: You should try the `logging` module. Just add a `StreamHandler` and a `FileHandler` to your logger... (see also https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is (assuming "path" is defined already):

```
def print_twice(*args,**kwargs):
    print(*args,**kwargs)
    with open(path,"a") as f:  # appends to file and closes it when finished
        print(file=f,*args,**kwargs)
```

Exactly the same thing will be printed and written to the file.  The logging module is overkill for this simple task.

Please tell me that you don't actually think that writing data to a file in Python requires messing around with stdout like in your code.  That would be ridiculous.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH PAUL.

Your function example above helped me in the same goal, and I replace every print function in my old script with this new amazing function.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the 'w' mode to the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) function wich erase any content in the file.
You should use the 'a' mode for appending in the file.

BTW you should consider using the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging) module with two handlers. One writting to stdout and the other to a file. See [logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.handlers.html) in the python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output on the screen and save them on a text file as well, then:

```
python <your-script-name> | tee output.txt
```

Can change "output.txt" to any file name you want. Ignore, if I misunderstood your question.